# How to get Google Spreadsheet values from Android native app(2020th year)

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-workspace

As of 2020, from the Android native application,
Get publicly available Google Spreadsheet values
What is the right way?

There are two methods I am currently using.

1. [G Suite APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/android?hl=ja#step_5_setup_the_sample)
2. [Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)

However, the 1 was not helpful because the content was modified.

(This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212295/using-the-google-sheets-api-after-completing-quickstart-tutorial) is inferred from what is different from what is referenced)

And I feel that the 2 is too much to do.

So, in addition to these, from the Android native application,

Please let me know if there is any way to get the value of the published Google spreadsheet.